# Is it still necessary to implement `compute_output_shape()` when defining a custom tf.keras Layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have implemented a custom `Layer` in `tf.keras`, using TensorFlow 2.1.0.

In the past, when using the stand-alone Keras, it was important to define the `compute_output_shape(input_shape)` method in any custom layer so that the computational graph could be created.

Now, having moved to TF2, I found out that even if I remove that method from my custom implementation the layer still works as expected. Apparently, it works both in eager and graph mode.
This is an example of what I mean:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np


class MyLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs[:, :-1]  # Do something that changes the shape


m = Sequential([MyLayer(), MyLayer()])
m.predict(np.ones((10, 3)))  # This would not have worked in the past
```

Is it safe to say that `compute_output_shape()` is not necessary anymore? Am I missing something important?

In the documentation there's no explicit mention of removing `compute_output_shape()`, although none of the examples implements it explicitly.

Thanks

Comment: You can generally omit the `compute_output_shape()` method, as tf.keras automatically infers the output shape, except when the layer is dynamic. In other Keras implementations, this method is either required or its default implementation assumes the output shape is the same as the input shape.

Comment: According to [Implementing custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers), is using `__init__`, `build` and `call`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not mentioned in the Tensorflow Documentation but in **Chapter 12**,  **Custom Models and Training with TensorFlow** of the book, **Hands-on Machine Learning using Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow (2nd Edition Updated for Tensorflow 2)** of O'REILLY Publications, written by Aurelien Geron, it is mentioned as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

To answer your question, yes, it is safe to say `compute_output_shape` is not needed unless the Layer is Dynamic.

This is evident from this [Tensorflow Tutorial on Custom Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers) where `compute_output_shape` is not used.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You are really the warrior of Tensorflow. Help friend with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612084/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-157-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expe

Comment: What exactly is a *dynamic* layer?

Answer (score -1):

I think it may be that when you use input_shape in the build method of your layer, it means it is a dynamic layer

Comment: This answer is morelike a comment. If you are not sure of answering, please use the comment section to help the asker

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32429330)